# Go - How to Combine Multiple Strings To Output a Unique 'Compressed' String?

Tags: go, ip

In Go, I'm trying to mix an **IP address** with a **username** to output some sort of compressed unique string.

*For example:* `"MyUsername" + "192.354.32.245" = "JDU7DNd"`

Comment: do you have a compression rate in mind?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Try creating a hash using FNV and encode that via base32.

Comment: I'm trying to make a chat room and I need each user when they choose a username to have a unique id. I have found on my school computers, all the IP's are the same so it wouldn't work if I just use the IP address as the id.

Comment: why don't you just use an uuid for each user @Acidic ? do you have length constraint?

Comment: [universal unique ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), and here is a generator: https://www.uuidgenerator.net/, and this lib `github.com/satori/go.uuid` helps you generate using go :)

Comment: So this UUID creates a "random" string? And this is what I will use for each user?

Comment: yes, if you just want a meaningless string to be its id. If your user amount is small enough, you could just use DB record id.

Comment: Okay so it looks like UUID would be an option. Also I've managed to write a function with Martin's idea of FNV hash. I just hashed both strings and got the sum of it. https://play.golang.org/p/8iq4zvUBa1

Comment: yup that's also can :) it highly depends on your use case actually, if you want the id to be meaningful, you need to use some other approach. But so far i think a meaningless ID like fnv hash or uuid will serve the purpose well.

Comment: Okay cool.. thanks for the help. I guess I'll write an answer to this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **[UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)** can be generated for each user which will generate a random 128 bit value.

However, for a static output, I have written a function which will hash and sum multiple strings which will output a unique value.

```
func Combine(string ...string) uint32 {
    h := fnv.New32a()

    for _, a := range string {
        h.Write([]byte(a))
    }

    return h.Sum32()
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/W_6GUTRJ6b

---

*Contributors:
    [Martin Gallagher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/687438/martin-gallagher) (fnv), [nevets](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2629095/nevets) (uuid).*

Comment: Create the fnv instance outside of the loop and Write() inside the loop, then return h.Sum32() - https://play.golang.org/p/W_6GUTRJ6b